# d3 and angularjs ng route svg is not destroyed after changing route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have angular program with 2 routes using ng-route. On the one route called 'this', I have some text and on the second route called 'that', I have some text and and a d3 directive. The directive generates svg and displays more text.

A plunkr example is shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/utJr0REcjavslOks57zN?p=preview)

The problem is when I switch from 'that' link back to the this 'link' the svg still remains furthurmore, if I click the 'that' link again I get another svg so that I 2 svgs instead of just one. If I keep clicking this and that I get more and more svgs.

What I want is when I switch from the 'that' link, back to the 'this' link    I want the svg to disappear.

How can I make the svg dissappear when I click the 'this' link, after I have clicked the that 'link'?

Below is my code:

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Route Problem</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/this', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/this.html', 
        controller: 'ThisCtrl'
    })
    .when('/that', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/that.html',
        controller: 'ThatCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/this'});
}])
.controller('ThisCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {}])
.controller('ThatCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) {}])
.directive('textSvg', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({
                width: 500,
                height: 200
            });
            svg.append('text').attr({
                x: 50,
                y: 50
            }).text('A simple message for testing');
        }
    }
})
```

this.html

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/this">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/that">That</a></li>
</ul>
<p>This is the route called this<p>
```

that.html

```
<p>This is the route called that.</p>
<text-svg></text-svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending svg to the body append it to your directive 'text-svg'

```
var svg = d3.select('text-svg').append('svg').attr({
```

Comment: Thank you baklazan. That fixed it